# How to prevent validation of Django ModelForm

Tags: jquery, django, validation, modelform

Is there a way to prevent the validation of a submited Django ModelForm?

The reason is that I have two select fields within that form and I alter the related table using Ajax.
Therefore I and need to reload the form in order to be able to select the new/changed values and I don't want all the validation errors.

Edit:

My initial plan was to set the hidden field "refresh" and submit the form (Ajax).
In create_component I wanted to check the value of refresh, and return the rendered but not validated form and replace it using jQuery. 
I expected form.is_valid() to trigger the validation proccess, but unfortunately I get a validated form if I render the form without calling is_valid.

**views.py**

```
def create_component(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = ComponentForm(request.POST)
    if request.POST.get('refresh',False):
      return render(request, "component_form.html", {"form":form})
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      return redirect("material")
  else:
    form = ComponentForm()
  return render(request, "create_component.html", {"form":form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class ComponentForm(ModelForm):
  refresh = BooleanField(widget=HiddenInput, required=False)
  class Meta:
    model = Component
    fields = ['name', 'articlenumber', 'manufacturer', 'vendor', 'price', 'picture', 'notes']
    labels = {
      'name': _('Bezeichnung'),
      'manufacturer': _('Hersteller'),
      'articlenumber': _('Artikelnummer'),
      'vendor': _('Lieferant'),
      'price': _('Preis'),
      'notes': _('Notizen')
    }
    widgets = {
      'picture': HiddenInput
    }
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code in question, or what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get a validated form if I render the form without calling is_valid

...this sounds wrong to me.

I think your actual problem here is here:

```
if request.POST.get('refresh',False):
```

...when inspecting the raw post var like this (unprocessed by your form) the value will always be a string, so it will always compare as `True`

(specifically, if you check src of `BooleanField` in `django/forms/fields.py` they have a comment which states *"check for the string 'False', which is what a hidden field will submit for False"*)

So the reason you get a validated form is because your code is following the `form.is_valid` code path.

You might find it easier to remove the `refresh` field from your form class (which I assume is only needed for purposes of your hack) and instead manually append `?refresh=1` querystring to the POST url from your javascript.  This will be easier to parse in your view:

```
if int(request.GET.get('refresh', '0')):
```

Comment: This seems to be the best way to handle my problem, it doesn't clutter my ModelForm and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django error messages: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-a-message

Do an AJAX post to the current url view. You can then use AJAX to request and display the form errors in a div or p inside the form. No refresh needed.
Here is an example inserting a comment with AJAX, Django 1.9, and Python 2.7:

forms.py:

```
#comment form
class InsertComentForm(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'id': 'comment', 'placeholder': 'Enter a Comment'}),required = True)
```

views.py:

```
#inside comment view
InsertComent = forms.InsertComentForm()     
if request.is_ajax():        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        InsertComent = forms.InsertComentForm(request.POST)            
        if request.POST.get("InsertCommentSubmit") is not None: #error            
            if request.POST.get("comment")=="":
                message = "Comment field cannot be empty!"

                return HttpResponse(message)                           

            elif User.objects.filter(username = request.user.username).exists():        
                if InsertComent.is_valid():
                    article_id = Article.objects.get(title=Slug, pub_date= aTimestamp).pk
                    article_id = article_id
                    user_id = request.user.id

                    p=Comment(comment=InsertComent.cleaned_data['comment'], article_id=article_id, user_id=user_id, date=date.today(), flagged=0, ipAddress=get_ip(request))
                    p.save()

                    message="Thanks for commenting!"                                  
                    return HttpResponse(message)    
            else:
                 messages.error(request,  "Login to Comment!"); 
    else:
        message = "Not Ajax"
        return HttpResponse(message)
```

Template:

```
       <form id="commentForm" class="col-md-12 djangoForm" action="" method="POST">
            <p class="formMessage" id="error_msg_comment"> </p><!-- Needs Space for style, AJAX Errors Here-->                          
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" id="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
        </div>
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ InsertComentForm.comment }}
        </div>

       <input id="InsertCommentSubmit" name="InsertCommentSubmit" class="Button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send" onclick="return InsertCommentForm()"/>           
       </form>
```

AJAX:

```
//Do not forget to pass the csrfmiddlewaretoken!
function InsertCommentForm(){
    var comment=document.getElementById('comment').value; //change from name to id!
    var csrfmiddlewaretoken=document.getElementById('csrfmiddlewaretoken').value; //change from name to id!    
    var InsertCommentSubmit=document.getElementById('InsertCommentSubmit').value;//change from name to id!

    var dataString = 'comment='+ comment+ 
        '&csrfmiddlewaretoken='+ csrfmiddlewaretoken + 
        '&InsertCommentSubmit='+ InsertCommentSubmit;
    $.ajax({

        type: "post",
        url : "",
        data:dataString,
        cache:false,
        success: function(html){
            if (html==0){
                window.location.reload();              
                //document.getElementById("commentForm").reset();                
            }else{
                $('#error_msg_comment').html(html);              

            }         
        }

    });
    return false;

}
```

I hope you can build on or use this example!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution that fits my needs.
I submit the form using an Ajax call, take the updated select out of the response and replace the original select with that:

```
$("#id_refresh").val(1);
$.post(
    $("form").attr("action"),
    $("form").serialize(),
    function(d) {
        $("#id_manufacturer").replaceWith($(d).find("#id_manufacturer"));
        $("#id_refresh").val(0);
    }
);
```

May be a hacky way of doing it but it works for me.